# Intellij - Numbers in `Intention Actions` window

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I was wondering. Is it possible to add number shortcut to corresponding actions inside `Intention Actions` window? Like with `String Manipulations` plugin:

[image]

For example in this case:

[image]

I would love to press `Alt+Enter` and then `3` to `Create object buzz` - I know for a lot of cases I can use shortcut for example ctrl+alt+v for a variable extraction but not for all.

I was looking for this kind of plugin but without a result

Comment: No, it is hardcoded. Maybe create a feature request.